# JQuery on("submit") not executing on the 1st click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using JQuery to test the size of an input after submitting a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <form method="post" action="essai.php">
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="email" placeholder="mail"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validate" />
 </form>

   <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo($_POST['mail']);
            if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
                $data=789;
            }

        }


    ?>

  <script>

    $(function(){
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
        $("form").on("submit", function() {

            if(data.toString().length < 4) {

                alert(data);
                return false;

                }

        });
      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the alert (if I enter only 1 caracter for instance) does not pop up after the 1st submitting but only after the others.

Thank you

Comment: because when you access the page for the first time `var data` will be empty.

Comment: @arisalsaila but when I submit the form, the POST variable is not empty right ? and then in my code it supposed to be passed the var data (and it actually is), the problem is that it does not go into the function ` $("form").on("submit", function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's terribly insecure to embed PHP code within JavaScript. I can't think of one reason why you will want to use server-side code on the client-side. As an alternative, echo the javascript code from PHP, not the other way round.

Now your problem comes up because the first time the page is loaded, nothing is posted. You have some chunk of code which executes only after something gets posted. If your PHP script can display errors, you will see an `undefined variable` notice thrown the first time you load the code. You can work around that by declaring the variable before using it in the condition:

```
     $data = 0; // Initialize variable here

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo($_POST['mail']);
        if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
            $data=789;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is still the same, I don't retrieve the value of `$_POST['submit']` once I have clicked the 1st time after the page has loaded

Comment: So, what I understand now, is that the PHP is executed on the server side and the Javascript on the client side. My problem is that the onsubmit JQuery function get executed before the PHP get executed, so I think I need another JQuery function, that "wait" until it receive the $_POST value..

Comment: @aurelSon I think you haven't tried my code. I executed it locally and it works exactly the way you want it to. There's an alert when you click the first time even before the page reloads. Did you notice the variable initialization?